# How does jQuery listen for DOM events being fired?

Tags: jquery, dom, event-handling, dom-events

How does jQuery know when any DOM event happens?

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('working');
});

document.body.onclick; // null
```

I rely on this library way too much.  Can someone tell me how it knows when the body is clicked?

Comment: It probably uses `addEventListener` (and IE's equivalent): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener. Since jQuery is open source, you can also have a look at its source code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery.

Comment: @FelixKling, and normalize it for IE...

Comment: This is what you need: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.on` wraps `jQuery.event.add` (if you look at the jQuery source that is on line 2688).

This attempts to use a cached version of the event type, but if there is none it eventually boils down to calling the browser-specific functions for attaching events (on around line 2767).

```
if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
    elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandle, false );
} else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
    elem.attachEvent( "on" + type, eventHandle );
}
```

It doesn't seem to have a fallback for the case of neither of these, so the `on*` attributes are never written to.  Hence, `elem.onclick` will be empty if you use `jQuery.on`

For reference: http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js

Comment: How does it know if it's already cached?  By cached do you mean when you bind the same handler function on the same element for the same event type multiple times in a row?

Comment: @danronmoon exactly; jQuery manages bound events internally as part of the element data

Answer (score 3):

jQuery (thanks God) doesn't use the `onclick` attribute or property of the DOM element, instead it uses the `addEventlistener` or IE- `attachEvent`